# How to make exception for a bash script with set -ex

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that has `set -ex`, which means **the running script will exit once any command in it hits an error**.

My use case is that there's a subcommand in this script for which I want to catch its error, instead of making the running script shutdown.

E.g., here's `myscript.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

set -ex

# sudo code here
error = $( some command )
if [[ -n $error ]] ; then
#do something
fi
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure but would `$(some command || true)` work?

Comment: What you say is not entirely true. The command means, to exit if an **unguarded command** returns a **non-zero exit code**, and also **write a trace** of the execution of your script to standard error. Why are you turning on this option if you don't like its behaviour?

Comment: Just put the command inside an `if` statement or behind an "or" operator (`||`). This will prevent the script from exiting due to `set -e`. For example: `some cmd || echo cmd failed >&2` or `if ! some cmd; then echo cmd failed >&2; fi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the output of a single command

```
this_will_fail || true
```

Or for an entire block of code

```
set +e
this_will_fail
set -e
```

Beware, however, that if you decide you don't want to use `set -e` in the script anymore this won't work.

Comment: Thanks! the `set +e` and `set -e` block really helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle a particular command's error status yourself, you can use as the condition in an `if` statement:

```
if ! some command; then
    echo 'An error occurred!' >&2
    # handle error here
fi
```

Since the command is part of a condition, it won't exit on error. Note that other than the `!` (which negates it, so the `then` clause will run if the command fails rather than it succeeds), you just include the command directly in the `if` statement (no brackets, parentheses, etc).

BTW, in your pseudocode example, you seem to be treating it as an error if the command produces any output; usually that's not what you want, and I'm assuming you actually want to test the exit status to detect errors.